# What does the Fourier transform of $\cos \pi x$ look like?

Tags: fourier-transform

If the operator $F$ means Fourier transform, what does the graph of $F[\cos \pi x] = \pi(\delta(\omega - \pi) + \delta(\omega + \pi)) $ look like?

I can see that this is two impulses which is exactly two upward pointing arrows at $\pm \pi$ representing infinity, but what does multiplying the impulses by $\pi$ do graphically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of plotting it

[image]

In this representation, the actual value of the vertical scale does not give you any additional information

Comment: Does the $\pi$ value even matter than?  Since if it's the same image then isn't it the same as $\delta(\omega - \pi) + \delta(\omega + \pi)$?  Or is the $\pi$ just there for a reverse transform purpose?

Comment: @OliverG It does matter, it tells you something about the amplitude of the original function $\cos \pi x$.

Comment: So the $\pi$ is just additional information about the original function that isn't included in the frequency graph but is known because of it's relation to the original function?

Comment: @OliverG $F$ is a linear operator $F[\alpha f + \beta g] = \alpha F[f] + \beta F [g]$, so the amplitudes definitely matter. However, In this particular case, a graphical representation of $F$ as the one above is not particularly affected by the amplitude. But that doesn't imply that it is not important in general